# KOTLIN: How to assign a default valor for a generic type parameter in a function?

Tags: kotlin, generics, types

My problem is simple (Maybe not the solution...)

I've defined a generic pointer:

```
data class pTp<T>(   // It's a generic wrap class for scalar type T
  var v:T
)
```

I what that this generic pointer works with many structured data:

```
data class Agenda (
 var name: String="",
 var address: String=""
)
```

If I want to use that type in a function, no problem:

```
fun example(...., pAg: pTp<Agenda>, .....){

}
```

The below function call works smoothly

```
var agen: pTp<Agenda> = pTp(Agenda())
... example(...,pAg=agen,...)
```

or

```
... example(...,pAg=pTp(Agenda()),...)
```

However, the below code for having a default value for this parameter it doesn't work...

```
fun example(...., pAg: pTp<Agenda>=pTp<Agenda>(Agenda()), .....){

}
```

Neither

```
fun example(...., pAg: pTp<Agenda>=pTp>(Agenda()), .....){

}
```

However, it's the same code that I've used in the initialization of the caller!

So, I don't know how to do this initialization.

**UPDATE**: The right answer is below. Just use a space before `=`. Crazy!

Comment: It's `pTp`. My mistake. I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use next syntax and it will work:

```
fun example(pAg: pTp<Agenda> = pTp(Agenda())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's just use a space before "=", but it's weird!
In no other cases that I know it's necessary....

Comment: If I declare  a variable of this type, Kotlin also demands a space before `=` and the initialization. I know that the code is more readable, but it's ridiculous....